# MYSQL HOW TO COMPARE STRING

Tags: mysql, string, compare, locate

I'm missing something, if I define variable

```
var1='ùy'  
var2='ùY' 
search='ùY1234'
```

why

```
LOCATE(var1,search) and LOCATE(var2,search) return 1  ?
```

and

```
SELECT var1=var2  return 1  ?
```

Thanks

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

String matching in mysql is done using a collation, and by default it's case-insensitive, which is why those strings match.

Answer (score 0):

Change your default collation or set the collation on the string explicitly: `'uY' COLLATE binary`